# Full-width footer won't stick to the bottom

Tags: css, magento, sticky-footer

I didn't managed it to stick my full width footer to the bottom of my webpage. When the main content above the footer is beneath a certain height, there is a blank space underneath the footer. I've tried to use all kind of solutions like the folowing css code:

```
 html,body { margin:0; padding:0;min-height:100%;position:relative;}
 .wrapper { min-height:100%;   position:relative;_height:100% /* _height = for ie */  }
 .page { padding-bottom:400px; height:100%; }
 .footer { padding:0;margin:0 position:absolute; left:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:400px; }
```

Still the footer will stick to the bottom of the main content instead of the bottom of the page. I think there is nothing wrong with my css.

example: http://hertog-hengelsport.nl.testbyte.nl/checkout/cart/

I hope someone can point me to the solution!

Many thanks!

URL: http://hertog-hengelsport.nl.testbyte.nl
Platform: Magento 1.7.2

Comment: If you have a solution, accept the answer which provided. If you solved it yourself, write your own answer and accept that. Don't deface the title of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Use "position: fixed;" instead of absolute for the Footer

Comment: Thanks! The footer sticks now to the bottom. But now i've got the following problem: the footer won't scroll together with the page but stays where it is sticked.

Comment: Take care the Footer is a direct Child of body...

If this does not work post your HTML please...

Comment: Footer is indeed a direct child of 'Body'

Comment: Look at this simple example... you don't need a Wrapper with dirty Hacks, a Page etc. http://cssdesk.com/RrwvW

Comment: Solved! Thanks to both of you! I've tried to start from the bottom up with the simple example USER123... showed me. After that didn't work out because it still appeared before my content. That was because of the position: fixed; element. I reviewed the code that i used in the beginning and modified it. I deleted the margin and position elements in the .footer class by accident and that worked out for me! Many thanks and i hope someone else can use this example. Greetings, Jeroen

Comment: So mark this Problem with the "stackoverflow-way" as solved ;)

Answer (score 0):

.wrapper is position relative, that makes any child of it relative to the div and not to the page.

Comment: Thanks for all your help people. I removed the position attribute but nothing really changed. This can't be too difficult...

Comment: Solved!

Thanks to both of you!

I've tried to start from the bottom up with the simple example USER123... showed me. After that didn't work out because it still appeared before my content. That was because of the position: fixed; element.

I reviewed the code that i used in the beginning and modified it. I deleted the margin and position elements in the .footer class by accident and that worked out for me! 
Many thanks and i hope someone else can use this example.
Greetings,
Jeroen